Hibernate Statistics not counting the queryExecutionCount as expected
With my code I am enforcing the n + 1 problem in a many-to-one relationship between my entities.
To check for the n + 1 problem to be present I set up a Test.
When running the tests I can also see that there are 3 queries executed, but still hibernates statistics returns 1 query to have been executed. That is obviously wrong.
flush and clearing the entity manager in my test also should prevent caching issues.
This are the logs from the test:
Hibernate: insert into shelter (name,id) values (?,default)
Hibernate: insert into shelter (name,id) values (?,default)
Hibernate: insert into messages (name,shelter_id,id) values (?,?,default)
Hibernate: insert into messages (name,shelter_id,id) values (?,?,default)
Hibernate: insert into messages (name,shelter_id,id) values (?,?,default)
Hibernate: select a1_0.id,a1_0.name,a1_0.shelter_id from messages a1_0
Hibernate: select s1_0.id,s1_0.name from shelter s1_0 where s1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select s1_0.id,s1_0.name from shelter s1_0 where s1_0.id=?
Hibernate: drop table if exists messages cascade

Here is my code:
Entity One:
@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
data class Animal(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val name: String,

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "shelter_id")
    val shelter: Shelter
)

Entity Two:
@Entity
@Table(name = "shelter")
data class Shelter(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val name: String,
)

Repository:
@Repository
interface AnimalRepository: JpaRepository<Animal, Long> {}

RepositoryTest:
@DataJpaTest
class AnimalRepositoryTest @Autowired constructor(
    private val animalRepository: AnimalRepository,
    private val entityManager: EntityManager
) {
    private lateinit var hibernateStatistics: Statistics

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
//        // Initialize the Hibernate statistics
        val sessionFactory = entityManager.unwrap(Session::class.java).sessionFactory
        hibernateStatistics = sessionFactory.statistics
        hibernateStatistics.isStatisticsEnabled = true
        hibernateStatistics.clear()  // Reset statistics before each test

        // Insert initial test data
        val shelter = Shelter(name = "Happy Shelter")
        val shelter2 = Shelter(name = "Happy Shelter2")
        entityManager.persist(shelter)
        entityManager.persist(shelter2)

        val animal1 = Animal(name = "Lion", shelter = shelter)
        val animal2 = Animal(name = "Tiger", shelter = shelter)
        val animal3 = Animal(name = "Panda", shelter = shelter2)
        entityManager.persist(animal1)
        entityManager.persist(animal2)
        entityManager.persist(animal3)

        entityManager.flush()
        entityManager.clear()  // Clear persistence context to ensure fresh retrieval
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @Rollback
    fun `should execute one SQL query when finding all animals with shelter`() {
        // Perform the operation (fetch all animals with shelter)
        val animals = animalRepository.findAll()

        // Assert the result
        assertThat(animals).hasSize(3)
        animals.forEach { animal -> animal.shelter.name}

        // Check Hibernate statistics for SQL query count
        val executedQueryCount = hibernateStatistics.queryExecutionCount
        assertThat(executedQueryCount).isEqualTo(1)
    }
}

If you need more info let me know ;)

Hibernate statistics doesn't count getting individual entities by id as queries but as entities loaded. You could replace .findAll() with .findById(1) and hibernateStatistics.queryExecutionCount would be 0. To see the count of the loaded entities check hibernateStatistics.entityLoadCount.

As far as I know is hibernateStatistics.entityLoadCount the number of entities received from the query. So in case if you want to validate lazy loading it would be a good metric to use. But in my case I found a better stats called hibernateStatistics.entityFetchCount I think this gives me the number of entities which have been received by additional queries. At least in my tests it shows this behaviour but couldn't find proper docs yet

I agree that documentation on this topic is severely lacking. This article says that entityFetchCount counts entities loaded from the datasource, but then why entities loaded with entityManager.find or as a result of join don't count? @AndrinF.
